# Auto-Layout, animation, and layers in subview

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, autolayout

In a constraint based view, there are several labels(top), buttons(bottom) and a customized UIView subclass (the checkers), which is consisted of many CALayers.
[image: Before animation]
I am trying to animate the size of the view by removing and adding constraints:

```
// self.containerWidth is a constraint instance 
// from Interface Builder Outlet, which is set to
// constrain the width of the whole view.
[self.calendarContainer removeConstraint:self.containerWidth];

[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 animations:^{
    [self.calendarContainer addConstraint:
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.calendarContainer 
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
        toItem:self.view 
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
        multiplier:0
        constant:700]];
    [self.calendarContainer layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

After animation, the view looks as this:
[image: After animation]

During the animation, the labels(top) and buttons(bottom) were moving smoothly according to the duration given above, **however, the checker view was bouncing very quickly to the final state before any other transitions occurred.**

I suspect that there was something intermingled with some CATransaction implicitly.

In the checker view, I rearranged the frames of layers in `-layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (!self.layer.sublayers.count) {
        [self prepareLayers];
    }
    int rowCount = [self rowCount];
    CGFloat rowHeight = [self rowHeight];
    [self.layer.sublayers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CALayer *rowLayer = obj;
        NSNumber *rowIndex = [rowLayer valueForKey:@"rowindex"];
        if (rowIndex) {
            NSUInteger rowIndexValue = rowIndex.integerValue;
            if (rowIndexValue < rowCount) {
                rowLayer.hidden = NO;
                rowLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, rowHeight * rowIndexValue, self.frame.size.width, rowHeight);
                [rowLayer.sublayers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj2, NSUInteger idx2, BOOL *stop2) {
                    CALayer *cellLayer = obj2;
                    NSUInteger colIndex = [[cellLayer valueForKey:@"cellindex"] integerValue] - rowIndexValue * 7 - 1;
                    cellLayer.frame = CGRectMake(colIndex*self.frame.size.width/7, 0, self.frame.size.width/7, rowHeight);
                }];
            } else {
                // hide
                rowLayer.hidden = YES;
            }
        }
    }];

}
```

How can I correct these animations?

BTW, where is the most recommended place to insert these layer re-positioning code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the effect was resulted from an implicit animation of layers.

The following code may fix all animation mismatches.

```
NSTimeInterval duration = 4.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:@(duration)
                     forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    CAMediaTimingFunction *func = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:func];
    [self.calendarContainer removeConstraint:self.containerWidth];

    [self.calendarContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.calendarContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0 constant:700]];
    [self.calendarContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    [CATransaction commit];
}];
```